# Forticlient VPN IPsec is UP but not able to ping any server/VMs after upgrade to MAC OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, vpn, ipsec, macos-big-sur, forticlient

Forticlient VPN `IPsec` is UP but not able to ping any server/VMs after upgrade to `MAC OS Big Sur`.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: I have the same problem, any breakthrough since your question ?

Comment: No solution yet

Comment: @Charleshaa, I found the solution. Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- FortiClient developers need to update the VPN client for Big Sur.

**- Other Solution:-**

- Go to -> System Preference -> Network -> Click on (+).
- Select Interface as VPN and "Cisco IPSec" as VPN Type.

  [image: VN]
- Enter the "IP Address, name & password".
  [image: IP Address]
- Enter secret shared key and group name
  [image: Enter secret sha]